# How can I select an entity by it's NBT tag?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't know why this command failed to find the creeper.

```
# Summoned via
/summon minecraft:creeper 208.46 79.00 -74.56 {Fuse: 9999,Health: 1,ignited: 1}
# Testing selector
/execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:creeper,nbt={ignited:1}] run tellraw "true"
# Also tried
/execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:creeper,nbt={ignited: 1}] run tellraw "true"
/execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:creeper,nbt={ignited:1b}] run tellraw "true"
/execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:creeper,nbt={ignited: 1b}] run tellraw "true"
```

Comment: Exact matching, `1b`

Comment: @FabianRöling I have tried that, and not succeeded. (added all I came up with...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for `/tellraw` is

```
/tellraw <targets> <message>
```

You didn´t specify a target, so the command fails to execute. You can just add @a and it will work.

```
/execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:creeper,nbt={ignited:1b}] run tellraw @a "true"
```

Comment: I feel dumb, as the command does not complain about not having a message, I thought `@a` was optional

Comment: I do stupid mistakes, too, you have maybe seen one of those "I'm stuck in a kill loop" questions? I've been there, too (but I didn't ask, I just deleted the world, it was new anyway). For the record: `kill @e` is not a good command for a repeating command block that is always active

Comment: Amazing command! :D Had blast reading it :D And With this little help, I did the **creeper proxymity based mobGriefing rule activator**!